# Turning circle, similar to car tire

Tags: c#

I have this code for draw circle in C#:

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(300, 300, 50, 50);
g.FillEllipse(brush, r);
```

i have a problem  with rotation circle in c#.

i have a circle like car tires,i want to rotate forward.

just like that :
[image]

Comment: Use a `RotateTransform`? But the bottom of the elliptical tires won't track with the road unless you also include some calculation to move the center up and down.

Comment: Here it is : http://tinyurl.com/qxgrhux

Comment: plase help me with code for rotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, each `Graphics` object has a method called `RotateTransform`, however this rotates the stuff only around the (0,0), we have to combine it with `TranslateTransform` to rotate stuff around any point (in this case, the point should be the center point of your circle):

```
Rectangle r = new Rectangle(300, 300, 50, 50);
int dx = r.Left + r.Width/2;
int dy = r.Top + r.Height/2;
float alpha = 45;//rotate 45 degrees clockwise
g.TranslateTransform(dx, dy);
g.RotateTransform(alpha);
g.TranslateTransform(-dx,-dy);
g.FillEllipse(brush, r);
```

**Update**: I've tried this demo code for you, it's a wheel running from the left edge to the right edge and reverse back and forth... I've tried to improve its performance but it seems to be the limit of `winforms`, you can see the wheel running with flicker, enabling `DoubleBuffered` does help a little but not good enough to make it stop flickering. Try this yourself.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        center = new PointF(startOffset+r, r + 30);
        t.Interval = 1;
        t.Tick += (se, e) =>
        {
            if (s >= ClientSize.Width - r*2 - startOffset) dir = -1;
            else if (s <= startOffset) dir = 1;                
            center.X += dir * step;
            Invalidate();
        };
        t.Start();
        DoubleBuffered = true; 
        Paint += Form1_Paint;           
    }
    Timer t = new Timer();
    PointF center;
    int r = 130;
    float s;
    float step = 1f;
    int dir = 1;
    int startOffset;        
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        s += step * dir;                        
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        Wheel(s, e.Graphics);                        
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Green, 
                          new RectangleF(center.X - r, center.Y - r, r * 2, r * 2));
        //draw this line to see how the wheel runs
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, new PointF(center.X - r, center.Y), 
                                      new PointF(center.X + r, center.Y));
    }        
    public void Wheel(float dx, Graphics g)
    {            
        float f = (float)(dx * 180 / (r * Math.PI));
        g.TranslateTransform(center.X, center.Y);
        g.RotateTransform(f);
        g.TranslateTransform(-center.X, -center.Y);            
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: thx. but i have rotation and Moving Forward

Comment: @user3042161 it requires a little much code here, doing so at least requires a timer, calculate the `dx` corresponding to the rotated angle ...

Comment: i try but can not calculate rotation angle.

Comment: @user3042161 see my update for the whole code, it's not really good (with `step = 1`, it's OK), but that's all I can do, `winforms` does not support much capability to render animating stuff. Anyway you can learn the algorithm here.